# How to know when ScheduledExecutorService is completed

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Sorry for my somewhat confusion but i am getting a little confused and need some assistance with concurrency.

If i have a thread pool in a class which calculates some value every 10 seconds such as this

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executorService.schedule(callable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

How can I determine when the result has come back. When the result is ready I need to process a map and do some calculations and then delete / empty the map

The only way I can think of is to user Observable interface but I am guessing this is not the correct approach

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you initiate the followup action from within the scheduled task? That would be the most natural approach.

Comment: Have a look at the return type of `schedule()` method?

Comment: It returns a scheduled future < integer> however - this essentially won't run once, it will run continuously with the number changing, so do i just need to keep checking for scheduled future.isdone in a loop? once is done is true i have a new result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) and invoke [isDone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) (because ScheduledFuture extends Future) like this

```
ScheduledFuture schedule = executorService.schedule(callable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
schedule.isDone()
```

Comment: Hi I added a comment at the top which questions is done a little. Thanks

Comment: @Biscuit128 so you want to invoke/perform multiple actions when  isDone() returns true ?

Comment: Basically it's a lottery game but the number will keep changing every x seconds when it's done I need to do some checks of who won

Comment: Have you Taken a look at FutureWatcher utility https://gist.github.com/samhendley/6030565